# Why is my translated content loaded on a 'raw' node address even when there is an alias given? (Multilingual Site)

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases, multi-sites

I have two languages (English and Spanish) in my Drupal site. The default language (English) content has already been created and now I need to translate the content (articles/pages/blocks) into Spanish for the respective entities. Let's say there is an *About Us* page which has an alias as '/about-us'. Now, when I go ahead and translate this to Spanish (enabling all the language modules and enabling content translation), it already has the alias mentioned in the edit page as about-us and the language is set to Spanish. Once I move ahead and save the translated content, it gets saved in the system assigned node address, say /es/node/40. Now, when I open /about-us, it opens the page with the English content, but when I use the language switcher to switch the language to Spanish, it takes me to /es/node/40 instead of /es/about-us.

Can somebody help me identify a method to rectify this problem?

Comment: Check your pathauto patterns at `/admin/config/search/path/patterns` - are there language specific configurations for your URL aliases?

Comment: No, there are no language specific configurations that I have set up in the pathauto patterns. I don't see any automatically generated patterns either. Do you think it will work if I add such a pattern (focused on the multilingual aspect of my website) in the patterns list?

Comment: An URL alias is basically a translatable content entity, and any node can have multiple aliases pointing to that node. If you don't have any pathauto patterns, Drupal will not magically invent or duplicate translations for foreign languages.